# Install iOS application using MDM

Tags: ios, iphone, mdm

We have provided an ipa file to client and they are trying to install it using MDM on there registered mobile devices. This MDM is entirely managed by client and we are ONLY providig ipa file to them.

However, when they are trying to install the app they are getting below error.

> Unable to insall "my-app". Please try again later

We have generated ipa file using Ad-Hoc option. This application we have developed using ionic and angularJS.

So do we need to specify any settings/configuration which will work with MDM also?

Any help on this appreciated !

Comment: You can't supply an ad hoc build unless the provisioning profile includes the UDID of every device they want to install it on. If they have an enterprise program membership they can provide access to that and you can sign the app for distribution that way or you can use a standard developer program membership and distribute the app to them privately through App Store connect and Apple Business Manager.

Comment: @Paulw11 Thanks.. Can we provide enterprise build instead of ad hoc build from x code using Developer account? And whatever build we will provide, we have to use clients apple id instead of ours?

Comment: If the client has an enterprise program membership then they can add you to their team and you can build/sign using that. If they don't have an enterprise program then you can upload a build to App Store connect using your own developer program and make it available as a custom app under Apple Business Manager

Comment: If  we upload using our Developer program using app store connect, how client can see on there Apple Business Manager account?

Comment: They have to provide you with their Apple business manager id. You put that in the distribution section of the App Store connect

Comment: Ok.. So you are saying we can distribute from testflight to apple business account?

Comment: No, not TestFlight. You follow the standard App Store process, including submitting for review, but under the availability setting for your app in AppStore Connect you nominate the Apple Business Manager identities that can download your app. It never appears on the store.

Comment: Ok.. But our app already got rejected for App Store due to business reasons.. Our client is using third party mdm and they do have ABM account... Clients devices are already registered on third party MDM..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215644/discussion-between-paulw11-and-xamdev).